# How to call or use function of cshtml file from one cshtml file?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I want to call function of one cshtml file from another cshtml file with parameters. Both files are cshtml files. And while pressing button from one page it should redirect on another web page and also execute functionality there. I know one way that I should include in js file and use that js file in both pages. But I am looking for any other way using jQuery or Ajax call.

```
window.location.href = redirecturl;
```

I want redirection on another web page and execute function of that page.

Answer (score 2):

Your reciderection Url must contains parameter like that

```
window.location.href = '/User?name=test&surname=foo';
```

Comment: When I use this code for redirection of url.It works.But then after redirection how can I call that function of cshtml file in current cshml file.I

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a C# Method of a page by another one.

To do it, you just have to make an ajax request, targeting as url the other page, followed by the method.

Comment: I did ajax call.But while excuting that it give me error of function not defined.. remember funtion is is another page.

Comment: So it's a javacript function and not a C# method

Comment: yes.or else is there any way to pass parameters with redirect url? and on load of that rediretced page we will check that paramters and simply call that function there.

Comment: no, you must add the function to the javascript of the other page

Answer (score 0):

I used localStorage.setItem and   localStorage.getItem for saving one comman variable value which I need in both cshtml file.
  Added redirection link in one cshtml file of another cshtml file and on load of that second cshtml file used store value of  localStorage.getItem in one varibale and cleared value of  localStorage.getItem .So,further it can not be used anywhere else.
  And call the need function in load event with conditions. 
This is the easiest way...!!!